# 3D binning in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I wonder if there is a faster solution to the problem below than using loops.

I have a set of points scattered in 3D space, with a value assigned to each point. So something like `dataPoints = [x1, y1, z1, v1; x2, y2, z2, v2; ...]`. The 3D space is evenly split into subvolumes `dx`×`dy`×`dz`. I need to create a matrix containing the sum of `v`'s in each subvolume.

The number of subvolumes and data points can be pretty big, on the order of 1 million each. So loops are really to be avoided.

I can easily find out, which subvolume a point belongs to:

```
ix(:) = floor(x(:) / dx) + 1;
iy(:) = floor(y(:) / dy) + 1;
iy(:) = floor(z(:) / dz) + 1;
```

However now I need to add up all points with the same tuple `(ix, iy, iz)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
 sums = accumarray( { iy(:), ix(:), iz(:) }, v(:) );
```

Comment: Always a +1 for `accumarray()` :)

Comment: Between `accumarray` and `bsxfun` I feel like I'm a MATLAB god compared to my peers.

Comment: Thanks! I really need to get to grips with `accumarray`.